# Calculating the trajectory arc of a projectile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, physics

I am trying to move an image across the screen in an arc... think flappy birds launcher. The image starts at the bottom left of the screen. When 'launched' I want it to move / animate in an arc across the screen as if launched.

I can animate the image in a linear (up and right) trajectory but cannot figure out how to get it to curve and start dropping.

The image is placed at the bottom left of the screen.

Inside a setTimeout method that runs every 0.01 seconds I have:

```
left += 10;
top -= 10;
$image.animate({left: '' + left + 'px', top: '' + top + 'px' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track velocity as well as position.

```
const GRAVITY = 2; // acceleration due to gravity, in pixels/tick
x = 0;
y = 0;
deltaX = 10;
deltaY = -10;

function tick() { // your setTimeout method
  x += deltaX;
  y += deltaY;
  deltaY += GRAVITY;
  $image.animate({left: `${x}px`, top: `${y}px` });
}
```